# Enum not Validating in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I've spent hours trying to work this out to no avail.

I am using Orchard 1.6 source and DataAnnotations. My `strings` are decorated with `[Required]` as is my `enum`. Yet, client validation will only work on the textboxes on my page (`strings`), the `enum` (radio button list) will not fire validation (nor does it show up  as `class="input-validation-error"` in the html source).

Here is my `enum`:

```
public enum Referral
    {
        [Display(Name = "Google / Google+")]
        Google,
        [Display(Name = "Bing / Yahoo / Other Search Engine")]
        OtherSearch,
        [Display(Name = "LinkedIn")]
        LinkedIn,
    }
    public class ReferralSelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
    {
        public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
        {
            return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<Referral>();
        }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one referral option")]
    [Display(Name = "How did you hear about us?", 
        Description = "Letting us know how you reached us helps us 
        to focus our advertising efforts and ultimately lowers costs")]
    [ReferralSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 8)]
    public virtual Referral? ReferralRadioButton { get; set; }
```

I am not sure why this is not firing. Any thoughts?

Note: I have tried just about everything I could find on the subject. I've registered the appropriate jquery scripts (validation, unobtrusive, etc.) with a special ResourceManifest.cs file. I've included it in my view. I've re-added model validation in a special Shell.cs file (IOrchardShellEvents or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I split out the enum and selector into their own classes, referenced them, then instead of using web.config to enable client validation, just plopped the html.helper in the view.